# jQuery UI :data selector does not return HTML5 data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, selector

Let say I have this piece of HTML :

```
<div id="container">
   <ul>
       <li><a href="#" data-some-info="foo">Bar</a>
       <!-- repeating a few like the one -->                          -->
       <!-- above for a while ...        -->
   </uL>
</div>
```

And I want to apply something to all the anchor elements with the data `some-info` when it is defined.

I just want to understand why this behaviour (is it a bug?)

```
$("#container").find("a:data(some-info)").size();  // -> 0
$("#container").find("a").data("some-info");       // -> "foo"
$("#container").find("a:data(some-info)").size();  // -> 1 (actual expected val)
```

Any ideas?

**More Info** : I'm using jQuery 1.9.0, and jQuery UI 1.9.2

** **Edit** **

I *know* about `$("#container").find("a[data-some-info]")`. This is not what I question here. If there is a [data selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/), why does it behave this way?

Comment: Is there any available documentation for the `:data` selector? My guess is it's a jQuery css selector that only looks at element data that has already been cached (that would explain the behavior you are seeing at least)

Comment: Ah, it's added by jQuery UI. Note how the documentation doesn't reference it selecting by data attribute at all.

Comment: @KevinB, you might be onto something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :data selector is not part of JQuery core. It might be a bug, but the JQuery docs say that HTML5 data attributes are pulled into the internal JQuery data object (presumably on calls to `.data`) rather than being available as part of a `:data` pseudo-selector (which according to the JQuery UI docs queries the internal data representation *as is* and says nothing about HTML5 data attributes)

Alternate approach:

Use `$("#container").find("a[data-some-info='foo']")`, or for if anything is set on the data attribute, `.find("a[data-some-info]")`.

Comment: no, I'm asking why the [data selector](http://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/) behaves this way.

Comment: So far, you seem to have the correct answer. ... looks like a undefined behaviour in all case (not well documented)

Comment: I'd propose a fix to the JQuery UI folks to make the `:data` selector work more like calls to `.data`, but it might be this way for performance reasons. I think the use case is to select things set by prior calls to `.data(key, val)` mixing CSS and internal storage.

Answer (score 3):

This is how the selector is implemented:

```
$.extend( $.expr[ ":" ], {
    data: $.expr.createPseudo ?
        $.expr.createPseudo(function( dataName ) {
            return function( elem ) {
                return !!$.data( elem, dataName );
            };
        }) :
        // support: jQuery <1.8
        function( elem, i, match ) {
            return !!$.data( elem, match[ 3 ] );
        },
```

(Ref. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L160)

Note how it is using `$.data` rather than `$(elem).data`. This means it is only looking for data that has been stored on the element through either the `$.data` or `$().data` method. It does not look for data attributes on the element and i do not think it is intended for that purpose. The attribute equals selector is what you should be using. `[data-foo]` Note however that it looks at the attribute, if you add data to an element with jQuery's `$().data` it may not match that selector if jQuery doesn't update the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

From Docs,

> The expression `$( "div:data(foo)")` matches a `<div>` if it has data stored via `.data( "foo", value )`

And from jquery code ->

> jQuery `data()` is stored in a separate object inside the object's internal data
>   cache in order to avoid key collisions between internal data and user-defined
>   data (comment from jQuery code)

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L51

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L63

When it is defined in the HTML, it is just a user defined data element which will NOT be selected by the jQuery `:data` selector.

However when you call `.data(some-info)`, it actually reads the user defined data and copies it to the internal data and later using `:data` picks up the element as it could find it in the internal data.

It is **NOT** a bug, as this is clearly mentioned in the docs.

---

You should use `.length` which is a property to get the number of returned elements from the selector.

Also `.size` is deprecated since as of **jQuery 1.8**. http://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: `length` or `size`, it doesn't change anything. But I'll keep that in mind about `size` :)

Comment: It's not a bug, but it's clearly an unexpected behaviour, since when you call .data(some-info) the user data are returned.